# Remove "all" button in portfolio filter and auto display specific filter button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've try to display portfolio image with filter, but I want to remove "all" button and automaticlly display specific filter button.

I've refer to [this link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/portfolio-gallery-with-filtering-category)

filter.js

```
$(".filter-button").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        if(value == "all")
        {
            //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.filter').show('1000');
        }
        else
        {
//            $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
//            $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
            $(".filter").not('.'+value).hide('3000');
            $('.filter').filter('.'+value).show('3000');

        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio">
            <section class="header">
                <h1 class="heading">Our Work</h1>
                <span>A taste of our creativity</span>
            </section>

            <!-- EDIT -->

            <div align="center">
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="towera">Tower A</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="towerb">Tower B</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default filter-button" data-filter="3d">3D Unit</button>
            </div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: can you share your html code as well please?

Comment: @ZombieChowder done sir

Comment: ok, what is the `specific filter` that you want after you remove the `all` button?

Comment: @ZombieChowder I want to auto displaying `towera` images when someone access my website sir, but for now, even i've remove `all` button, portfolio filter still display all images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite on the right path of actually accomplishing this. You've already changed your `data-filter` inside the `button` class.

I would suggest not to remove the `ALL` button but rather to leave it, so you can preview all the images once you've filtered them.

The jquery code you've provided will pretty much be the same, the only difference between the example will be that you'll have to change the images in the links and the tags in the `button` class.

Here is a JS Fiddle with pretty much the same example, just with the filter names changed.

[JS Fiddle with an implemented example.](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35384/)

Comment: So how to make it display `towera` first? It's possible?

Comment: I think I know what @RedRiver want, you just set ' $(".filter").not('.towera').hide();  $('.filter').filter('.towera').show(); '
before the click function, demo like below
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/35385/

Comment: I was use @zombieChowder code, he almost do all you want, and I'm also suggest keep  'all' show at first when user access your page

Comment: @RedRiver yes, with those updates, it should display just the `towera` images.

Comment: That's what i want @Anami thanks for the code, you too zombie for suggest me the best way method,